# Gnuplot: x axis scale for 1-column data spaced every two seconds

Tags: plot, gnuplot, scale, axis

I have 1 column of data:

```
plot "memory.log" w lp notitle pt -1 lw 1
```

Time spacing between records is 2 seconds. How can I plot it in [hours] scale insteadt of [2 seconds] scale on x axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot "memory.log" using (column(0)*2/60):1 w lp notitle pt -1 lw 1
```

should work. See "pseudocolumns". The parenthesis around the first using parameter are required when doing math.

Gnuplot "pseudocolumns".
expressions in the using clause of a plot statement can refer to additional
bookkeeping values in addition to the actual data values contained in the input file. These are
contained in "pseudocolumns".

```
column(0)   The sequential order of each point within a data set.
              The counter starts at 0 and is reset by two sequential blank
              records.  The shorthand form $0 is available.

column(-1)  This counter starts at 0 and is reset by a single blank line.
              This corresponds to the data line in array or grid data.

column(-2)  The index number of the current data set within a file that
              contains multiple data sets.  See `index`.
```

Comment: Yes, using pseudocolumn 0 is the way to go, but for 2 second intervals in hours I would use `(column(0)*2/3600)`.

Comment: oops, you are correct

Answer (score 3):

To define an x axis measured in hours, against which you will plot time measured in seconds, you need the following commands:

```
  set xdata time
  set xtics format "%.3tH"
  set xlabel "Hours"
  plot "memory.log" using (2*$0) : 1 with lines
```

The format specifier "tH" means hours relative to some arbitrary time 0, in your case the start of data collection. "%.3tH" means gives you three decimal places of precision in printing the time value (e.g. 10 seconds is 0.003 hours).

(2*$0) means two times the input line number.  I.e. line N corresponds to 2N seconds on x.